# Incorrect float subtraction result

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, floating-point

DataSet

```
   id   qty CheckIn CheckOut
   5    10      1     0
   5    10      0     1
   5    1.6     1     0
   5    0.4     0     1
   5    0.4     0     1
   5    0.4     0     1
```

I am trying to select remaining quantity of `id` `5`.

**Query:**

```
Select 
    (select SUM(qty) from tbl where id = 5 and CheckIn = 1) -
    (select SUM(qty) from tbl where id = 5 and CheckOut = 1)
```

**Expected Output:** `4.0`

**Original Output:** `3.9999999`

Even the individual queries return perfect values:

```
select SUM(qty) from tbl where id = 5 and CheckIn = 1  -- returns 11.6
select SUM(qty) from tbl where id = 5 and CheckOut = 1 -- returns 11.2
```

But subtraction gives `3.9999999`

---

You can generate data using the below query:

Here is the query to generate data set

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl](
    [id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [qty] [float] NULL,
    [CheckIn] [bit] NULL,
    [CheckOut] [bit] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl] ([id], [qty], [CheckIn], [CheckOut]) VALUES (5, 10, 1, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl] ([id], [qty], [CheckIn], [CheckOut]) VALUES (5, 10, 0, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl] ([id], [qty], [CheckIn], [CheckOut]) VALUES (5, 1.6, 1, 0)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl] ([id], [qty], [CheckIn], [CheckOut]) VALUES (5, 0.4, 0, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl] ([id], [qty], [CheckIn], [CheckOut]) VALUES (5, 0.4, 0, 1)
GO
INSERT [dbo].[tbl] ([id], [qty], [CheckIn], [CheckOut]) VALUES (5, 0.4, 0, 1)
GO
```

Comment: Floating point is approximate. Some values doesn't do well when converted to/from binary machine format. Maybe you should have a decimal data type instead, or double precision?

Comment: @jarlh: It's not that binary floating point itself is approximate - it's that it doesn't exactly represent all *decimal* values. (A decimal data type is just as "approximate" if you try to represent base 3 numbers, for example.) I agree with the suggestion of using a decimal data type (not double) though.

Comment: @JonSkeet I have a lot of data in the table, it would be difficult to change the datatype. Is there any other way?

Comment: I'm afraid making a poor decision about which data type to use is a fundamentally costly mistake. Basically, you haven't actually got "0.4" in your table... you've got the nearest float value to 0.4. Fixing the data type is definitely the best course of action here.

Comment: but this query return **0.4** , `SELECT (CAST(11.6 as float) - CAST(11.2 as float))` why it does n't make the same mistake ?

Comment: As in this query you are using same precision numbers as compared to your above query which include **SUM** function that return some approximate value

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN CheckIn = 1 THEN qty END) AS MONEY)
    -
    CAST(SUM(CASE WHEN CheckOut = 1 THEN qty END) AS MONEY)
FROM tbl
WHERE id = 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved by changing data type to decimal